# Eureka client fetching registry from Eureka server

Tags: netflix-eureka, netflix

Is there any possible way to find all instances of eureka server from a eureka client ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can register Eureka server itself in the registry.

i.e. In eureka-server

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
```

Now Eureka server instance details will be available when you query the Eureka server from other clients.